# Laravel scheduler run as nobody?

Tags: laravel-5

Currently by default scheduler will run as root, I'd like to run as nobody, how can I make it?

`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Would the nobody get access to all files you need to run it though? What is the real reason of doing it?

Comment: the scheduler will write logs to storage/logs/*.log as root, but I deploy laravel as nobody, nobody can't write logs since then